# I cant position my form user agent style?

Tags: html, css, forms, margin

I am trying to position my form in the center of the screen everytime i try to add margin-top  it gets overwritten by user agent style and it stays at 0em and instead the margin applies to my whole body and my nav bar comes down to the same level as my form   left works im not sure what I can do ive tried playing around by creating a div and moving that I also tried padding.

css form{
       margin-top:200px; }

```
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="script/send_form_email.php">

<table width="450px">

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td valign="top">

  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>

 </td>

 <td valign="top">

  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>

 </td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">  

 </td>

</tr>

</table>

</form>
```

Comment: show your markup and css

Comment: @joel  the form is in the same body the nav is in a div seperate of the form

Comment: seems to work for me.  Show your exact css code